# How to deal with NA values in a categorical variable?

Tags: r, rename, missing-data, data-cleaning, categorical-data

I am facing a strange issue and I hope someone can help out.
I have a facto variable with 8 classes (levels) as follow in R :

```
> levels(data_testing$land_cover)
[1] "COMMERCIAL"                   "GOVERNMENT AND INSTITUTIONAL" "NOT AVAILABLE"              
[4] "OPEN AREA"                    "PARKS AND RECREATIONAL"       "RESIDENTIAL"                
[7] "RESOURCE AND INDUSTRIAL"      NA
```

as you can see it is shown that NA is one of the levels of the variable "land_cover. and the frequency of the levels is as follows:

```
COMMERCIAL GOVERNMENT AND INSTITUTIONAL                NOT AVAILABLE
                         236                          150                          469
                   OPEN AREA       PARKS AND RECREATIONAL                  RESIDENTIAL
                         908                          108                         6034
     RESOURCE AND INDUSTRIAL                         <NA>
                        1584                         2505
```

So it says there are 2505 values of NAs. However, when I calculate the total  missing value of such a variable,  it shows there is none:

```
sum (is.na(data_testing$land_cover))
[1] 0
```

My question is if anyone knows how I can rename, revalue this `NA`? I tried to replace or rename `NA` to something else but `NA`s cannot be identified as a level.

My ultimate goal is to add all `NA` values to the class "NOT AVAILABLE" and get rid of the `NA` class. But, apparently, in the replace or revalue functions, the `NA` cannot be recognized as a class.

I truly appreciated your help in advance.

Cheers-

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(data_testing$land_cover))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with the `levels` of your vector. I don't know how it was created (assuming it was done programmatically), but let's compose a similar vector and show why it does not match your tests.

First, a `factor` is merely an `integer` vector with two differences: an attribute of `"levels"`, which is a string vector of the levels; and it is classed as a `"factor"`.

```r
dput(factor(letters[1:3]))
# structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")
```

Let's construct one manually:

```r
vec <- 1:3
attr(vec, "levels") <- c("A", "B", NA, "D")
vec
# [1] 1 2 3
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "A" "B" NA  "D"
```

Not yet a factor, so the integers still show not-`NA`.

```r
class(vec) <- "factor"
vec
# [1] A    B    <NA>
# Levels: A B <NA> D

dput(vec)
# structure(c(1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("A", "B", NA, "D"), class = "factor")

attributes(vec)
# $levels
# [1] "A" "B" NA  "D"
# $class
# [1] "factor"
```

So we've done nothing to the integers within `vec`, but now one of them shows up as an `NA`. Interesting.

Unfortunately, we know that underneath the `factor` class, the numbers are still 1, 2, and 3, not `NA`, so we shouldn't be totally surprised with this:

```r
is.na(vec)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
as.integer(vec)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

To find out which of `vec` *references* an `NA`, though,

```r
as.character(vec)
# [1] "A" "B" NA 
is.na(as.character(vec))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And to find out which of the *levels* is `NA`:

```r
is.na(levels(vec))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you want to replace the *level* that is `NA`, you could try the following:

```r
lvls <- levels(vec)
lvls[is.na(lvls)] <- "NOT AVAILABLE"
levels(vec) <- lvls

vec
# [1] A             B             NOT AVAILABLE
# Levels: A B NOT AVAILABLE D
```

(I've never really liked how factors are shown without quotes, as the `Levels:` above can be vague.)

---

By the way, many of the helper functions try to keep you from doing this. For instance:

```r
vec <- 1:3
attr(vec, "levels") <- LETTERS[1:4]
class(vec) <- "factor"
dput(vec)
# structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")
attr(vec, "levels") <- c("A", "B", NA, "D")
dput(vec)
# structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", NA, "D"), class = "factor")
```

Notice how we have (i) still integers 1 to 3; and (ii) the `NA` level. If we do it formally, however,

```r
levels(vec) <- c("A", "B", NA, "D")
dput(vec)
# structure(c(1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("A", "B", "D"), class = "factor")
```

we've lost one of our integers! And we lost the `NA` level.